# RemoveEventListener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this very strange case that prevents me from removing `eventListener`. This is a very simple function that binds to keyboard events and unbinds (in theory) when is not needed.

Code is as follows:

```
const keyboardEvents = function(input, remove = false) {
    const { key, func } = input;
    const operation = remove ? 'removeEventListener' : 'addEventListener';

    function keyboardFunction(event) {
        console.log(event);

        if (event.keyCode === key) {
            func();
        }
    }

    window[operation]('keyup', keyboardFunction);

  if (remove) {
    console.log('REMOVED');
  } else {
    console.log('ADDED');
  }
};
```

And I run it with

```
keyboardEvents({ key: 27, func: testFunc }); // add event
keyboardEvents({ key: 27, func: testFunc }, true); // remove event
```

Problem is, the listener isn't removed. What can I do?

CodePen for reference: https://codepen.io/tomekbuszewski/pen/LzBZgP?editors=0010

I also tried without the `operation`, just writing

```
if (remove) {
  window.removeEventListener('keyup', keyboardFunction);
} else {
  window.addEventListener('keyup', keyboardFunction);
}
```

The result was the same.

Comment: its properly work on your fiddle

Comment: It's not, comments in the console are fine, but listener still remains (please refer to `Event Listeners` tab in Chrome Inspector).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the same function reference for removing from the event handler. Every time when you call the `keyboardEvents`, you create a new function with name 
`keyboardFunction`, so there are different from a call to call. So why you can't remove it.

Try this code [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGpMNK?editors=0010).

Comment: I see. So I should pass the `keyboardFunction` as an argument to `keyboardEvents`?

Comment: I tried defining it outside, but this didn't work (see updated fiddle).

Comment: @TomekBuszewski I am thinking. You need every time to have the same reference.

Comment: But one note, Why you on every `keyup` attach new eventlistener ?

Comment: This is very short-lived binding, so there's no point in creating a larger listener and keeping it around.

Comment: No, this shouldn't work like this. The listener is created whenever I invoke the `keyboardEvent` function (eg. when I create a modal that I want to be closed with `esc` key). Even now it's working like that.

Comment: I have added Codepen example. Look it. Currently it is working. But one logic must be added if you will click Add event listere more than one time in sequence.

Comment: You have a bit hard logic. So why extra steps are needed

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'll try to remove the `let` part though and have this a little prettier.

Comment: Comments make some things clearer, I think we should leave them.