# Remove Event Listener for Typescript does not work

Tags: typescript, ionic3, cordova-plugins, event-listener, ionic-native

I tried `import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms';` in my ionic 3 chat application. But `document.removeEventListener('onSMSArrive');` is not working.

here are the packages that I am using

```
"@ionic-native/sms": "^4.3.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "^4.3.0",
"cordova-sms-plugin": "^0.1.11",
```

The problem is when I come to my page 1st time it perfectly working and receives messages when I got SMS to the phone. **But if I went back to another page and come back to the page I receives the same message twice in my function.** I think event listener is not removing and when I navigate again to the page another listener is adding to the document.

Here is my code

I add event listener when page loads and I remove it when the page unloads.

```
public ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.smsService.startMessageListner();
}

public ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.smsService.stopMessageListner();
}
```

Here is the `startMessageListner()` and `stopMessageListner()` functions in my service.

```
public startMessageListner()
{
    --- some works do here ---
    this.startListner();
}

public startListner()
{
    this.recieveMessage().then((message) => {
        --- receives message here and when after 
            navigating multiple times I receives 
            multiple same messages here---
    }
}

public recieveMessage() {

    if (!window.SMS) { alert('SMS plugin not ready'); return; }

    window.SMS.startWatch(function() {
        console.log('Watching');
    }, function() {
        console.log('Not Watching');
    });

    this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', this.resolveMessage(resolve));
    });

    return this.promise;
}

public stopMessageListner()
{
    --- some works do here ---
    this.stopReciveMessage();
}

public stopReciveMessage()
{
    // ***This one also not works***
    // document.removeEventListener('onSMSArrive', (event)=>{
    //     window.SMS.stopWatch(function() {
    //         console.log('Stop Watching');
    //     }, function() {
    //         console.log('Not Stop Watching');
    //     });
    // });

    document.removeEventListener('onSMSArrive');

    window.SMS.stopWatch(function() {
        console.log('Stop Watching');
    }, function() {
        console.log('Not Stop Watching');
    });
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem. This issue wasted my whole week. And still no luck :(

**===Updated with comments===**

all given links say that I have to pass exactly same function while removing event listener. In my case, I am passing `this.resolveMessage(resolve)` with `resolve` parameter when I am calling `document.addEventListener`. So I already tried it as follows and still it not solved.

1. ```
   public recieveMessage() {

       --same content as above--

       let self = this; // I added this line for safe side
       this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           self.resolve = resolve;
           document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', self.resolveMessage(resolve),false);
       });

       return this.promise;
   }

   public stopReciveMessage()
   {
       document.removeEventListener('onSMSArrive', this.resolveMessage(this.resolve),false);

       window.SMS.stopWatch(function() {
           console.log('Stop Watching');
       }, function() {
           console.log('Not Stop Watching');
       });
   }
   ```

2.
        for same `recieveMessage()` in 1.

```
    public stopReciveMessage()
    {
        document.removeEventListener('onSMSArrive', this.resolveMessage,false);

        window.SMS.stopWatch(function() {
            console.log('Stop Watching');
        }, function() {
            console.log('Not Stop Watching');
        });
    }
```

3.
        for same `recieveMessage()` in 1.

```
    public stopReciveMessage()
    {
        let self = this;
        this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            document.removeEventListener('onSMSArrive', self.resolveMessage(resolve),false);
            window.SMS.stopWatch(function() {
                console.log('Stop Watching');
            }, function() {
                console.log('Not Stop Watching');
            });
        });
    }
```

4.
        for same `recieveMessage()` in 1.

```
    public stopReciveMessage()
    {
        let self = this;
        this.promise = (resolve, reject) => {
            document.removeEventListener('onSMSArrive', self.resolveMessage(resolve),false);
            window.SMS.stopWatch(function() {
                console.log('Stop Watching');
            }, function() {
                console.log('Not Stop Watching');
            });
        };
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Where do you call method `stopRecieveMessage`? Try to use `this.promise.unsubscribe();` instantly after send message.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I call stopRecieveMessage inside stopMessageListner().  Anyway, I get this error "this.promise.unsubscribe is not a function" when leaving form my page.

Comment: In order to remove an EventListener, you must pass the exact same function that has been passed through `addEventListener`, not an other function that has the same *content*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [removeEventListener is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825493/removeeventlistener-is-not-working)

Comment: Other possible targets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46704065/removeeventlistener-doesnt-work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43624322/why-removeeventlistener-is-not-working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444077/javascript-removeeventlistener-not-working

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for your comments, But I already tried those links. I have updated my question with your comments. could you please check ===Updated with comments=== section and give your comments.

Comment: Not sure how I can be clearer than all those answers, but You must pass the same exact function in both methods. So you have to keep a reference to the function passed in `addEventListener` in order to pass it later in `removeEventListener`. e.g., you could do `this._listener = 
this.resolveMessage(resolve);        document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', this._listener);` and then `document.removeEventListener('onSMSArrive', this._listener);`

Answer (score 5):

I agree it's a real pain to remove an event listener in typescript. I have solved it in Vue like this:

```
class App {

    mylistener:EventListener

    created(){
        this.mylistener = (e:Event) => this.logMessage(e,"hello")
        window.addEventListener('click', this.mylistener);
    }

    destroyed(){
        window.removeEventListener("click", this.mylistener)
    }

    logMessage(e:Event, str:String){
        console.log("click event was called")
    }
}
```

This assumes the "created" and "destroyed" functions are called when your component is created and removed. First check if you can get a basic example working, and if yes, see how you can apply it to your SMS library - that library may have issues of its own.